# Is "bigtable-hbase-beam" compatible with beam java SDK 2.5?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm following this documentation (specifically, Writing to Cloud Bigtable
):
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-dataflow-java
(I'm trying both versions 1.3.0 and 1.4.0.)

Before running a pipeline, this step gives an error:

```
CloudBigtableScanConfiguration config = new CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.Builder()
    .withProjectId("project-id")
    .withInstanceId("instance-id")
    .withTableId("table")
    .build();
```

(Note that the documentation does not state how this 'config' instance is created for the 'writing' section, but I tried both the above (copied from the 'reading' section followed by '.withScan()' line removed as well as `CloudBigtableTableConfiguration.Builder` instead of ScanConfig. The results are the same on my end.)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Preconditions
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.CloudBigtableConfiguration.setValue(CloudBigtableConfiguration.java:142)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.CloudBigtableConfiguration.<init>(CloudBigtableConfiguration.java:137)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.CloudBigtableTableConfiguration.<init>(CloudBigtableTableConfiguration.java:116)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.<init>(CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.java:178)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.CloudBigtableScanConfiguration$Builder.build(CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.java:160)
        at com.moloco.dataflow2.Main.main(Main.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

It appears that `Preconditions` is not found.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/c87f8aef59320f240697fb015dbbc7142a2a679f/bigtable-dataflow-parent/bigtable-hbase-beam/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/beam/CloudBigtableConfiguration.java#L143

We've had issues with Beam SDKs 2.0/2.1/2.4, so we are trying to migrate from 1.9.1 to 2.5, and the Bigtable connector is an important feature we utilize a lot.

Which Beam SDKs (java) is `bigtable-hbase-beam 1.3.0` compatible with, if not with 2.5 yet?

Among other things, we used the following:

```
compile group: 'com.google.cloud.bigtable', name: 'bigtable-hbase-beam', version: '1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:2.5.0'
```

Also tried `compile 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:2.5.0'`, but with the same error.

Update:
Gradle dependency tree suggests that the connector sdk requires beam 2.3+, so I tried 2.3 & 2.4. Unfortunately, it conflicts with other parts of our code and a known issue seems to be blocking us ([DataFlow Runner Fails after upgrading to Beam 2.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566375/dataflow-runner-fails-after-upgrading-to-beam-2-4-0) ).
Originally I asked about the version 1.3.0 (not knowing that 1.4.0 is available); but I still get the same error with hbase-bigtable 1.4.0 and beam sdk 2.5.

Comment: I've encountered a similar situation with the Cassandra JAR. Did anyone manage to solve this before? Posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254740/no-repackaged-dependencies-when-building-apache-beam-cassandra-jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in bigtable-hbase-beam.  [Here's the proposed fix](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/pull/1871).